# OpenCart 2.0.1.1 Top menu

Tags: menu, navigation, themes, opencart

After installing a new theme, comparison with add to cart button link is riding on each other. Waiting for your help with this solution.

1) http://i.hizliresim.com/RYkGEj.jpg = add to cart and 
2) http://i.hizliresim.com/ZDk5Gk.jpg = top menu

OpenCart version 2.0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some problem is css.You can add padding or margins and then see how it looks and then eventually you will be able to fix it.